# external program not on run menu

Tags: aptana, aptana3

The 'External Program' option has disappeared from my Run menu. I think it happened after my last software update of Aptana studio 3.

Does anybody have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your perspective. `Window -> Reset Perspective`